# How to get readable bytes in boost::asio::async_read

Tags: c++, boost-asio

I am having a problem while reading from boost asio socket asynchronously.
I have a client program which is writing randomly into socket.
I have a boost asio server which is supposed to read it and process it.

when I read it synchronously  `tcp::socket _socket .available()` function gives me exact
readable bytes whatever the  client is writing into it.
For eg .
If client is writing 9000 bytes first time and 500 bytes second time .First read is giving me 9000 bytes and second one giving me 500 bytes.

when I read it asynchronously, I am using the following function:

```
boost::asio::async_read(_socket,_response, boost::asio::transfer_at_least(1), boost::bind(&CMyclass::handle_read_header,
this,boost::asio::placeholders::error,
boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred));
```

Here bytes_transferred is always 512 and to read 9000 bytes of data it calls like 18 times.
Does any one have idea about this.

Comment: "*when i read it synchronously tcp::socket _socket .available() funtion gives me exactly readable bytes whatever the client is writing into it.*" => This is only pure luck. TCP is stream-oriented, not message-oriented so there is absolutely no guarantee that you can read the data in blocks of the same size that the client sent.

Comment: Thanks Syam... but is it possible to read it in bigger chunks than 512.

Comment: To force bigger chunks, create `transfer_at_least()` with the desired value.  For variable length payloads, it is fairly common to prefix the payload with a fixed-size header that contains the length of the payload.